# Send message from random date

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, python-datetime

I am trying to make my discord bot send a message from a random date in the server's history but the `around` argument doesn't seem to work properly

```
def random_date():
    d1 = date(year=2020, month=3,day=16)
    d2= date.today()
    delta = d2 - d1
    int_delta = delta.days
    random_number_of_days = random.randrange(int_delta)
    ran = random_number_of_days
    global day
    day = d1 + timedelta(ran)
    # en = d1 + timedelta(ran + 1)
    return day


    @commands.command(name='quote')
    async def quote(self,message):
        day = random_date()
        messages = await message.channel.history(around=day).flatten()
        msg = random.choice(messages)
        embed = discord.Embed(description=f'{msg.content}' , color=message.author.color, timestamp=msg.created_at)
        embed.set_author(name=f"{msg.author.name}#{msg.author.discriminator}", icon_url=msg.author.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name = 'Source' , value = f"[Jump]({msg.jump_url})")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Found in : #{message.channel.name}")
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel%20history#discord.TextChannel.history

You need to use datetime.datetime()
Also see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime if you need help with that